# How can I prove it by predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic

For every natural number there exists another natural number which is greater than it.

A greatest natural number has no natural number greater than it.

Therefore, there exists no greatest natural number.

Use N(x) to denote “x is a natural number,”

```
G(x,y) to denote “x is greater than y,”

T(x) to denote “x is a greatest natural number.”
```

Comment: Start translating premises and conclusion with the provided vocabulary.

Comment: "For every natural number..." is "$\forall x \ N(x)$ ..."

Comment: "... there exists another natural number..."  is "$\exists y \ N(y) \land y \ne x \ldots$".

Comment: And so on......